# Javascript Math Rounding

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

Okay, I have this script:

```
var x = new Date;
setInterval(function() {
    $("#s").text((new Date - x) / 60000 + "Minutes Wasted");
}, 30000);
```

It works perfectly fine. Except it sometimes gives me an answer like `4.000016666666666`. How can I round that? If I have to rewrite the script, that is okay. Thanks!

Comment: Did you even try the search feature ? There are plenty of duplicates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken) - many, many others.

Comment: Ehm, how about trying http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+round?

Comment: I've searched. I get some weird piece of code that I have to somehow put into my script.

Comment: Um... The closest I've gotten to a duplicate is <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken">this</a>.

Answer (score 14):

You can use Math.floor() function to 'round down'

```
$("#s").text(Math.floor((new Date - x) / 60000 + "Minutes Wasted"));
```

or Math.ceil(), which 'round up'

```
$("#s").text(Math.ceil((new Date - x) / 60000 + "Minutes Wasted"));
```

or Math.round(), which round either up or down, where it's closer to:

```
$("#s").text(Math.round((new Date - x) / 60000 + "Minutes Wasted"));
```

Answer (score 2):

`Math.round`?

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_math.asp

Comment: `Math.Round` _(sic)_ is not going to work; `Round` is not a constructor so doesn't start with a capital R.

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#s").text(parseInt((new Date - x) / 60000) + "Minutes Wasted");
}, 30000);
```

use `parseInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for simple Math round then here it is `Math.round(40.45);`